# easymock two setAttributes for one session

Tags: junit, easymock

I have created a session in the test class. and return it when getsession is called.

```
expect(request.getSession()).andReturn(session);
```

I have set two different attributes for the session as they are set in the method which I want to test.

```
session.setAttribute("name","xyz");
session.setAttribute("class", "A")'
```

When I call the method, in the when it tries to setAttribue, it causes a nullpointerexception.

Any help?

Comment: Can you please share your full test method?

Answer (score 0):

It can be problem if you set the values after making expect method.

```
User user=new User();
expect(mock.getUser()).andReturn(user);
user.setName("John"); //It should be above the expect line
```

Or you forget to call EasyMock replay() method on your mock after expect method.

```
// Setup the method of mock object
 expect(mock.getNum()).andReturn(2)
// Setup is finished need to activate the mock
 replay(mock);
```